# ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob clang: error: linker command failed

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode11

```
> Ld
> /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
> normal x86_64 (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
>     cd /Users/ajaysivan/MyApp/OfflineUpgrade/MyApp-offline-app/ios
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVLinearGradient
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNDeviceInfo
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTActionSheet
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sentry
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SentryReactNative
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-config
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation
> -L/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-netinfo
> -F/Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -filelist /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp.LinkFileList
> -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp_lto.o
> -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBVLinearGradient -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFolly -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNDeviceInfo -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTActionSheet -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lSentry -lSentryReactNative -lYoga -lc++ -lglog -lreact-native-config -lreact-native-geolocation -lreact-native-netinfo -lstdc++ -lz -framework Foundation -framework JavaScriptCore -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT
> -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent
> -framework JavaScriptCore -lRCTBlob -lRCTAnimation -lReact -lRCTActionSheet -lRCTGeolocation -lRCTImage -lRCTLinking -lRCTNetwork -lRCTSettings -lRCTText -lRCTVibration -lRCTWebSocket -lPods-MyApp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp_dependency_info.dat
> -o /Users/ajaysivan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fhlxfvymksoqhsglhalddkzaekrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

.

> ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob clang: error: linker command
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Getting the above error when building react-native project in Xcode11. I recently upgraded to react native 0.61.5 and everything works fine on android. No Idea why it is not working on iOS.

I'm really new to iOS and react-native. If you need any further information please ask.

Comment: Also seeing this. Any  solutions?

Comment: @YaronLevi I have added the solution that worked for me as an answer. Try it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have solved the issue by removing all react-native library linking from xCode by following these steps,

1. Open `Project.xcworkspace` file in xCode
2. Go to **project navigator** tab
3. Click on the project folder
4. Then select the project name in the **Targets** section
5. Open **Build Phases** tab
6. Expand **Link Binary With Libraries** section
7. Remove all binaries expect `libPods-Project.a`

Then rebuild the project.

[image]

Comment: I had to also do this to work:
`cd ios`
`pod install`
`cd ..`