# ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob

Tags: ios, react-native, upgrade

I'm currently trying to upgrade react-native to 0.61.5 from 0.59.10 and faced this error:

`ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I've tried `pod install`, `pod install --repo-update`, `pod update` and that:

1. Clear the cache of pod with:

1.1 `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`

1.2 `rm -rf Pods`

1.3 `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

1.4 `pod deintegrate`

1.5 `pod setup`
2. And delete the project's Pods directory. The location of it is project directory > ios > Pods.
3. Then in the project directory > ios location, install pod with `pod install`
4. And `react-native run-ios` in project directory.

Comment: Could you post your package.json and pod file here. I think it will be more helpful for others to help to you.

Comment: have you found the solution to it? as per my project issues, i found that its the issue with all the libRCT files. none of them are found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ld: library not found for -lRCTBlob clang: error: linker command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254299/ld-library-not-found-for-lrctblob-clang-error-linker-command-failed)

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10468349)'s question post.

> In your XCode you need to found `Build phases` link, then `Link Binary With Libraries`  select `lRCTBlob` and click -(minus) in the end of list